# L'Hospital rule kind of

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$ be two smooth functions (i.e. $f,g\in C^{\infty}([a,b])$. Is it true that, if for a fixed $t_0\in (a,b)$ with the property that$\ g(t)\neq g(t_0), \forall t\neq t_0$ the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{t\searrow t_0} \dfrac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{g(t)-g(t_0)}=L\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$$

then:

$$\exists \lim_{t\searrow t_0} \dfrac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}=L$$

? (i.e. the above limit exists and it is equal to the first one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t) = te^{-1/t^4}\sin (e^{1/t^2}), g(t) = e^{-1/t^4}$ for $t \ne 0,$ and define $f(0)=g(0)=0.$ Then $f,g \in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}).$ With $t_0 = 0,$ we have

$$\frac{f(t) - f(0)}{g(t)-g(0)} \to 0,$$

while $f'(t)/g'(t)$ oscillates wildly as $t\to 0.$